# How to pass multiple values in NavigateUrlFormatString of GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using `DevExpress Grid` in `ASP`. I want to pass multiple paraments in the query string of `GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn`. Following is my grid

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataSourceID="dsHotels" KeyFieldName="Id">
    <SettingsAdaptivity>
        <AdaptiveDetailLayoutProperties ColCount="1"></AdaptiveDetailLayoutProperties>
    </SettingsAdaptivity>
    <SettingsBehavior ConfirmDelete="True" />
    <EditFormLayoutProperties ColCount="1"></EditFormLayoutProperties>
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" VisibleIndex="0" Width="20%">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Id" FieldName="Id" Visible="False" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="EventId" FieldName="EventId" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn Caption="Start Date" FieldName="StartDate" VisibleIndex="3">
            <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="dd-MM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom" EditFormatString="dd-MM-yyyy">
            </PropertiesDateEdit>
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn Caption="End Date" FieldName="EndDate" VisibleIndex="4">
            <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="dd-MM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom" EditFormatString="dd-MM-yyyy">
            </PropertiesDateEdit>
        </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn Caption="Events" FieldName="Id" VisibleIndex="8">
            <PropertiesHyperLinkEdit NavigateUrlFormatString="EventDetails.aspx?id={0}&startdate={1}&enddate={2}&eventid="+<%= EventId %> TextField="TotalEvents">
            </PropertiesHyperLinkEdit>
        </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

How can I pass the `Id, StartDate, EndDate, EventId` column in the parameters of URL? I have tried to load it using `<%= EventId %>` but it does not work.

Comment: I think you can't use `<%= EventId %>` syntax because `NavigateUrlFormatString` uses specific string formatting. Did you got `Index out of range` message while trying `{1}`, `{2}` and so on? Usually `DataItemTemplate` with standard hyperlink is preferred when `NavigateUrlFormatString` cannot recognize the format.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Sir, Thank you very much, `DataItemTemplate` worked. I will share solution shortly.

Answer (score 1):

> Create GridViewDataTextColumn in ASPxGridView Columns

```html
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Total Events" UnboundType="String" VisibleIndex="8">
        <DataItemTemplate>
      <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="hyperLink" runat="server" OnInit="hyperLink_Init"></dx:ASPxHyperLink>
     </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

> Write following code in cs file

```
protected void hyperLink_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxHyperLink link = (ASPxHyperLink)sender;
        GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer templateContainer = (GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)link.NamingContainer;

        int rowVisibleIndex = templateContainer.VisibleIndex;

        //get the values of other column in the row
        string eventid = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "EventId").ToString();
        string id = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "Id").ToString();

        //create url
        string contentUrl = string.Format("events.aspx?eventid={0}&id={1}", eventid, id);

        link.NavigateUrl = contentUrl;
        link.Text = string.Format("Link Text Goes Here");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed from GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn to GridViewDataTextColumn

```html
 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Visible="false" FieldName="Id_Encabezado_Solicitud"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Visible="false" FieldName="Id_Oportunidad_Hija"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="ID Operación" UnboundType="String" CellStyle-ForeColor="#0000ff">
                                    <DataItemTemplate>
                                        <dx:ASPxHyperLink  ID="hpOperacion" runat="server" OnInit="hpOperacion_Init">
                                        </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                                    </DataItemTemplate>
                                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

And add this code

```
Protected Sub hpOperacion_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim link As ASPxHyperLink = CType(sender, ASPxHyperLink)
    Dim templateContainer As GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer = CType(link.NamingContainer, GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)
    Dim rowVisibleIndex As Integer = templateContainer.VisibleIndex
    Dim IdOportunidad As String = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "Id_Oportunidad").ToString()
    Dim IdOportunidad_Hija As String = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "Id_Oportunidad_Hija").ToString()
    Dim contentUrl As String = String.Format("~/Views/CartaCondiciones/Reprocesos/LineaCreditoR.aspx?id={0}&idh={1}", IdOportunidad, IdOportunidad_Hija)
    link.NavigateUrl = contentUrl
    link.Text = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "Id_Encabezado_Solicitud").ToString()
End Sub
```